# Hibernate search to find partial matches of a phrase

Tags: java, hibernate, lucene, hibernate-search, solar

In my project we are using hibernate search 4.5 with lucene-analyzers and solar. 
I provide a text field to my clients. When they type in a phrase I would like to find all `User` entities whose names include the given phrase.

For example consider having list of entries in database with following titles:

```
[ Alan Smith, John Cane, Juno Taylor, Tom Caner Junior ]
```

`jun` should return `Juno Taylor` and `Tom Caner Junior`

`an` should return `Alan Smith`, `John Cane` and `Tom Caner Junior`

```
    @AnalyzerDef(name = "customanalyzer", tokenizer = @TokenizerDef(factory = WhitespaceTokenizerFactory.class), filters = {
            @TokenFilterDef(factory = LowerCaseFilterFactory.class),
            @TokenFilterDef(factory = SnowballPorterFilterFactory.class, params = { @Parameter(name = "language", value = "English") })

    })
@Analyzer(definition = "customanalyzer")
    public class Student implements Serializable {

        @Column(name = "Fname")
        @Field(index = Index.YES, store = Store.YES, analyze = Analyze.YES)
        private String fname;

        @Column(name = "Lname")
        @Field(index = Index.YES, store = Store.YES, analyze = Analyze.YES)
        private String lname;

    }
```

I have tried with wildcard search but

[Wildcard queries do not apply the analyzer on the matching terms. Otherwise the risk of * or ? being mangled is too high.](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/4.5/reference/en-US/html_single/#section-creating-faceting-request)

```
Query luceneQuery = mythQB
    .keyword()
      .wildcard()
    .onFields("fname")
    .matching("ju*")
    .createQuery();
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 6):

First, you didn't assign the analyzer to your field, so it isn't used currently. You should use @Field.analyzer.

Second, to answer your question, this kind of text is best analyzed with an `EdgeNGramFilter`. You should add this filter to your analyzer definition.

**EDIT:** Also, to prevent queries such as "sathya" from matching "sanchana" for instance, you should use a different analyzer when querying.

Below is a full example.

```
@AnalyzerDef(name = "customanalyzer", tokenizer = @TokenizerDef(factory = WhitespaceTokenizerFactory.class), filters = {
        @TokenFilterDef(factory = LowerCaseFilterFactory.class),
        @TokenFilterDef(factory = SnowballPorterFilterFactory.class, params = { @Parameter(name = "language", value = "English") })
        @TokenFilterDef(factory = EdgeNGramFilterFactory.class, params = { @Parameter(name = "maxGramSize", value = "15") })

})
@AnalyzerDef(name = "customanalyzer_query", tokenizer = @TokenizerDef(factory = WhitespaceTokenizerFactory.class), filters = {
        @TokenFilterDef(factory = LowerCaseFilterFactory.class),
        @TokenFilterDef(factory = SnowballPorterFilterFactory.class, params = { @Parameter(name = "language", value = "English") })

})
public class Student implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "Fname")
    @Field(index = Index.YES, store = Store.YES, analyze = Analyze.YES, analyzer = @Analyzer(definition = "customanalyzer"))
    private String fname;

    @Column(name = "Lname")
    @Field(index = Index.YES, store = Store.YES, analyze = Analyze.YES, analyzer = @Analyzer(definition = "customanalyzer")))
    private String lname;

}
```

And then specifically mention that you want to use this "query" analyzer when building your query:

```
QueryBuilder queryBuilder = fullTextEntityManager.getSearchFactory().buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(Student.class)
    // Here come the assignments of "query" analyzers
    .overridesForField( "fname", "customanalyzer_query" )
    .overridesForField( "lname", "customanalyzer_query" )
    .get();
// Then it's business as usual
Query luceneQuery = queryBuilder.keyword().onFields("fname", "lname").matching("sathya").createQuery();
FullTextQuery query = fullTextEntityManager.createFullTextQuery(luceneQuery, Student.class);
```

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43047342/6692043

---

By the way, if your data includes only first and last names, you shouldn't use stemming (`SnowballPorterFilterFactory`): it will only make the search less accurate for no good reason.

Comment: I have added the analyzer in the class level, now i have updated. I have tried with EdgeNGramTokenFilter.class suggested by you, now what is the issue means, if i search with Sathya its giving result like sandhya, saravanan, sachin, sanchana and sathya. but i don't other names. it should search like '%sathya%'. Can you suggest any other filter for this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @PSKumar Right, you should use a different analyzer when querying. I updated my answer.

Comment: where is qb coming from, i'm trying to use the same way but then qb is not defined

Comment: @Tanah I fixed the example, `qb` should have been `queryBuilder`

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a standard `TypedQuery`?

(where `String term` is your search-term)

```
TypedQuery<Student> q = em.createQuery(
        "SELECT s " +
        "FROM Student s " +
        "WHERE s.fname like :search " +
        "OR s.lname like :search";
q.setParameter("search", "%" + term + "%");
```

Didn't test this one, but something like this should do the trick.

Comment: The SQL "LIKE" operator is extremely limited. The question is about using proper full-text, which allows very flexible control of how / what to match, and also happens to perform much better.