# NGramFilterFactory does not work correctly

Tags: lucene, full-text-search, hibernate-search, analyzer

i want to extract a keyword from a text

For example if nameEn = "Hello everybody TODAY" and i do the search for the keyword "body" it shows me the result

I used the annotation AnalyzerDef, but I have a problem in my code

I will explain the problem :

nameEn = "Hello everybody TODAY"

For example when i search for "b", it shows me the result

But when i search for "bo" or "bod" or "body", it shows me nothing

Now when i change minGramSize to 2

when i search for "bo", it shows me the result

And the other key words "b", "bod", "body" it shows me nothing

I do not know where the problem exactly is, because according to the code below, when i entered "bo"

Output will be: "b", "bo"

```
    @Indexed
    @AnalyzerDef(name = "autocompleteNGramAnalyzer", tokenizer = 
      @TokenizerDef(factory = StandardTokenizerFactory.class), filters = {
      @TokenFilterDef(factory = WordDelimiterFilterFactory.class),
      @TokenFilterDef(factory = LowerCaseFilterFactory.class),
      @TokenFilterDef(factory = NGramFilterFactory.class, params = { 
        @Parameter(name = "minGramSize", value = "1"),
        @Parameter(name = "maxGramSize", value = "50") }),
      @TokenFilterDef(factory = PatternReplaceFilterFactory.class, params = {
        @Parameter(name = "pattern", value = "([^a-zA-Z0-9\\.])"),
        @Parameter(name = "replacement", value = " "), @Parameter(name = "replace", value = "all") }) })
    @Analyzer(definition = "autocompleteNGramAnalyzer")
    public class Product implements Serializable {

    @Field(index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.YES, store = Store.NO)
    private String nameEn;
```

The search method:

```
    public List<Product> searchProduct(String keyWord) {
    FullTextSession fullTextSession = Search.getFullTextSession(getSession());
    try {
        fullTextSession.createIndexer().startAndWait();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    QueryBuilder queryBuilder = fullTextSession.getSearchFactory().buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(Product.class).get();
    org.apache.lucene.search.Query luceneQuery = queryBuilder.phrase().withSlop(2).onField("nameEn").boostedTo(5).sentence(keyWord.toLowerCase()).createQuery();
    org.hibernate.Query fullTextQuery = fullTextSession.createFullTextQuery(luceneQuery, Product.class);
    List<Product> result = fullTextQuery.list();
    return result;
}
```

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using a keyword query instead of a phrase query:`queryBuilder.keyword().onField("nameEn").boostedTo(5).matching(keyWord.toLowerCase()).createQuery();`

If, as the name of your analyzer suggests, you're doing autocomplete, the phrase query may not be relevant. In any case, this would be a first step towards getting stuff working.

On a side note, you may want to prevent the n-grams to be generated when analyzing the query (especially if you need phrase queries). For more on this, see the "**EDIT**" part in this answer: [Hibernate search to find partial matches of a phrase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44028095/hibernate-search-to-find-partial-matches-of-a-phrase/44029443#44029443)

Comment: I used the same example but when i used EdgeNGramTokenFilter.class it shows me this error: Type mismatch: cannot convert from Class<EdgeNGramTokenFilter> to Class<? extends TokenFilterFactory>

Comment: @AymenKanzari Right, there was a typo in the example: EdgeNGramTokenFilter.class should be EdgeNGramTokenFilterFactory.class. I fixed the example.

Comment: Note: there is not an EdgeNGramTokenFilterFactory.class, there is EdgeNGramFilterFactory.class. i have the same problem. exemple:
nameEn = [Juno Taylor, Tom Caner Junior, Alan Smith, John Cane, This Casual Shirt has a Mandarin collar... ].
'jun' return Juno Taylor and Tom Caner Junior,
'an' should return Alan Smith, John Cane, Tom Caner Junior and This Casual Shirt has a Mandarin collar... , but it returns nothing
, 'a' or 'n' should return all, but it returns nothing

Comment: @AymenKanzari : EdgeNGramFilterFactory only generate ngrams on the beginning edge of tokens, so alan will be transformed to ["a", "al", "ala", "alan"].
If you really want to generate *all* ngrams, replace EdgeNGramFilterFactory in my example with NGramFilterFactory.