# Hibernate Search with Lucene Query for first and last name together

Tags: lucene, hibernate-search

I have attempted this with phrase, wildcard and keyword queries but nothing really works perfectly.

```
  ...    
    @Field(name = "firstLastName", index = org.hibernate.search.annotations.Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.NO, store = Store.NO)
    public String getFirstLastName() {
        return this.firstLastName;
    }
...
```

Now I want to query this field and return the correct results if a user types John Smith, Smith John or Smith Jo* or John Smi*....

```
junction = junction.should(qb.keyword().wildcard().onField("firstLastName")
                            .matching("John Smith*").createQuery());
```

If I search for just Smith or John given a keyword query, I get a hit. I am not analyzing the field as I didn't think I needed to but I tried it both ways with no success...

Comment: I could write a custom analyzer and do it that way, but there has to be something else.

Answer (score 1):

Several issues here:

- You need to use an analyzer, be it only to split the strings on whitespaces. Define an analyzer and assign it to your field.
- You can't use wildcard queries if you want the strings to be analyzed: wildcard queries are not analyzed. You should use an EdgeNGramFilter instead.

This answer to a very similar question will probably help: [Hibernate Search: How to use wildcards correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46899947/hibernate-search-how-to-use-wildcards-correctly/46904863#46904863)

Comment: what is the best analyzer to use for name matching?