# Searching for a word that contains a 'query'

Tags: java, spring, lucene, hibernate-search

i've implemented the hibernate search orm (LATEST lucene_version) that search words contains a entry query :

```
    FullTextEntityManager fullTextEntityManager = Search.getFullTextEntityManager(entityManager);
    QueryBuilder queryBuilder = fullTextEntityManager.getSearchFactory()
            .buildQueryBuilder()
            .forEntity(Application.class)
            .get();

    Query queryName = queryBuilder
            .keyword().fuzzy().withEditDistanceUpTo(2).withPrefixLength(2)
            .onField("name")
            .matching("*" + q + "*")
            .createQuery();
```

this queryName cannot find words like 'Wikicrédit' or 'Wikipro' or 'WikiCash' if my query is 'q=Wiki'

How can i enhance those instructions to get words that start with 'Wiki%' independently of edit distance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either:

1. Use the [`simpleQueryString` query](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.11/reference/en-US/html_single/#elasticsearch-query-sorting) and type your query as `Wiki*`.
2. Declare a separate `name-edgengram` field with an edge-ngram analyzer that will index `Wikicrédit` as `[W, Wi, Wik, Wiki, Wikic, Wikicr, ...]` and then query that field, as desribed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46904863/6692043).

Comment: how can i return exactly "Wikipro" if my query is "Wikipro" ?

Comment: @Mirlo Not sure what your problem is, but if you used the edge-ngram analyzer and searching for `Wikipro` returns documents containing `Wikicrédit`, then you probably forgot to override the analyzer at query time. See the second part of [the answer I mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46904863/6692043) where I tell you to use `overridesForField`.