# FullTextField Hibernate Lucene analyzer not returning expect result

Tags: hibernate, lucene, full-text-search

I am trying to implement full text search: when the input search text will be "cherry" it should return "cherry 1", "cherry", "cherry 5", "cherry101", "cherryfruit". But it is only matching "cherry 1", "cherry", "cherry 5" not "cherry101", "cherryfruit".

My project is in Java spring boot with Mysql and I am using Hibernate with lucene backend version 6.1.7.Final.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate.search</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-search-mapper-orm</artifactId>
  <version>6.1.7.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate.search</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-search-backend-lucene</artifactId>
  <version>6.1.7.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

I am following the documentation but it does not work the same way it is described: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#getting-started-analysis

I added the following code:

```
package org.hibernate.search.documentation.analysis;

import org.hibernate.search.backend.lucene.analysis.LuceneAnalysisConfigurationContext;
import org.hibernate.search.backend.lucene.analysis.LuceneAnalysisConfigurer;

public class MyLuceneAnalysisConfigurer implements LuceneAnalysisConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void configure(LuceneAnalysisConfigurationContext context) {
        context.analyzer( "english" ).custom() 
                .tokenizer( "standard" ) 
                .tokenFilter( "lowercase" ) 
                .tokenFilter( "snowballPorter" ) 
                        .param( "language", "English" ) 
                .tokenFilter( "asciiFolding" );

        context.analyzer( "name" ).custom() 
                .tokenizer( "standard" )
                .tokenFilter( "lowercase" )
                .tokenFilter( "asciiFolding" );
    }
}
```

added the property in the application.properties file

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.search.backend.analysis.configurer=class:org.hibernate.search.documentation.analysis.MyLuceneAnalysisConfigurer
```

And added the follwing

```
@FullTextField(analyzer = "name") 
    private String name;
```

Answer (score 0):

I do think Your configuration works as expected. Cherryfruit and cherry101 are not valid english words. That is why You can not find them in Your index.

Can You try it with [this configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46899947/hibernate-search-how-to-use-wildcards-correctly), to validate my claim please?