# Hibernate-Search - Case insensitive wildcard search using lucene query parser syntax (not using QueryBuilder!)

Tags: java, lucene, wildcard, hibernate-search, case-insensitive

Firstly, here is my Hibernate-Search indexing time setup:

```java
// ...
@Indexed(index = "XXXRequestIndex")
@AnalyzerDef(name = "toLowercaseAnalyzer",
    tokenizer = @TokenizerDef(factory = KeywordTokenizerFactory.class),
    filters = {
        @TokenFilterDef(factory = LowerCaseFilterFactory.class)
    })
public class XXXRequest implements Serializable {
    // ...
    @Field(analyze = Analyze.YES, store = Store.YES, analyzer = @Analyzer(definition = "toLowercaseAnalyzer"))
    @SortableField
    private String status;
    // ...
}
```

I saw this thread where `.overridesForField(...)` is setup on `QueryBuilder` for a field at query time in order to query case-insensitive with wildcards:
[Hibernate Search | ngram analyzer with minGramSize 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43044350/hibernate-search-ngram-analyzer-with-mingramsize-1/43047342#43047342)

I need to do something similar for a particular field only ("status"), but I am **NOT** using a `QueryBuilder`, instead I am parsing an incoming lucene query string using an `MultiFieldQueryParser`. I cannot change that to switch to build a query using a `QueryBuilder` because it is important for the callers of the code to issue their own dynamic queries using the lucene query parser syntax (like described more or less in https://lucene.apache.org/core/2_9_4/queryparsersyntax.html)

So when the caller sends as lucene query `status:*n\ Pr*`, it does not match "In Processing".
However a query like `status:*n\ pr*` does match "In Processing".

My query code:

```java
Analyzer analyzer = new KeywordAnalyzer();
String[] fields = ...
MultiFieldQueryParser queryParser = new MultiFieldQueryParser(
    fields,
    analyser);

Query luceneQuery = queryParser.parse(luceneFilterString);
List results = fullTextQuery.getResultList();
```

How can I make the query be case-insensitive?

Answer (score 2):

Wildcard searches are not analyzed by the `MultiFieldQueryParser` so you have to do the filtering yourself (so you need to apply the filters manually to your input string).

Another option would be to use the simple query string feature (see https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#_simple_query_string_queries), which can apply analysis to this sort of query but it only supports prefix queries (so you can search for `process*` but not `*cessing`). If this limitation is acceptable for you, I really recommend this approach.