# lucene - search with contains value

Tags: hibernate, jpa, lucene, hibernate-search

I have a field socialReason in my database with the folowing values

- ch fleyriat
- CLINIQUE DENTAIRE MUTUALISTE
- CENTRE DE SOINS INFIRMIERS BETSCHDORF

for example, i want when i search with the word CH i get the values that contains CH, in my cas i want to get **ch** fleyriat and CENTRE DE SOINS INFIRMIERS BETS**CH**DORF

I tried with bolow code, but it return nothing

```
  @Field(analyzer = @Analyzer(definition = "test"))
  private String socialReason;

  public class CustomAnalyzerProvider implements LuceneAnalysisDefinitionProvider {
    @Override
    public void register(LuceneAnalysisDefinitionRegistryBuilder builder) {
        builder
        .analyzer( "test" )
                .tokenizer( KeywordTokenizerFactory.class )
                .tokenFilter( ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory.class )
                .tokenFilter( LowerCaseFilterFactory.class );
    }
  } 

  fullTextEntityManager.getSearchFactory().buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(ExerciseFrameworkEntity.class)
 .overridesForField("socialReason", "test").get();

  listOfQuery.add(getQueryBuilder().keyword().onField("socialReason").matching(socialReason).createQuery());
```

Answer (score 0):

You're after the `ngram` token filter, a filter that will generate a list of all substrings of each word in your index.

As you can imagine, this will generate a lot of data and thus your index will be very large. Only do this for reasonably small datasets.

See the analyzer configuration mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43044350/hibernate-search-ngram-analyzer-with-mingramsize-1/43047342#43047342), and see also the answer to that question to query this field correctly.

If you can, I would also recommend reconsidering your requirements: it's generally enough to match words that *begin* with what the user typed (in your example, word that begin with "ch"), and that can be implemented with a much lower overhead thanks to the *edge*Ngram tokenFilter. To do that, see [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46899947/hibernate-search-how-to-use-wildcards-correctly/46904863#46904863).

Comment: Sorry i made a typo in my question, i replace `overridesForField("socialReason", "edgeNgram")` by `verridesForField("socialReason", "test")`. I don't want the words that begin with "ch", i want the words that contains "ch". According to my understanding the `EdgeNGramFilterFactory, minGramSize="1", maxGramSize="10"` the analyzer transforms the word "ch fleyriat" to "c", "ch", "f","fl","fle","fley","fleyr","fleyri",fleyria","fleyriat", and the word "BETSCHDORF" to "B","BE","BET","BETS","BETSC","BETSCH"..., in this case when the user types "CH", it returns only "ch fleyriat".